# Remove Edit Profile option but still have the profile viewable

Tags: options, profiles

I am looking to make it so a subscriber can login and view their profile but not change any of their settings.  Only the admin can change the profile settings.  Again,  I am not looking to hide the profile completely, just to make it un-editable by the subscriber who's profile it is.

Comment: I am using the WP-Members plugin and have hacked a solution for the profile view on the front end of the website.  This leaves the 'Update Now" button but renders the input fields un-editable.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'wpmem_register_form_rows', 'prefix_profile', 9999, 2 );
function prefix_profile( $rows, $toggle ){
    if( 'edit' == $toggle ){
          foreach( $rows as $row_item ){
               $rows[$row_item['meta']]['field'] = preg_replace( '/<input(.*) value="(.*)" class="textbox"(.*)\/>/', '<p class="noinput">$2&nbsp;</p>', $row_item['field'] );
               $rows[$row_item['meta']]['label'] = str_replace( '*', '', $row_item['label'] );
          }
    }
    return $rows;
}
```